# Ubuntu 20.04: Titlebar buttons on the Left not working properly; titlebar disappears in Tweaks app

Tags: gnome, 20.04, window, gnome-tweak-tool

In Ubuntu 20.04, when I use the `Tweaks` app to change the titlebar buttons to the left (instead of the default right), the titlebar becomes greyed out (or rather black).

It seems that placing the buttons on the left does not leave enough space for the side navigation block with the default window size for `Tweaks`.

Sometimes, when I open `Tweaks` and I see the titlebar has been greyed out, I change the window size and the titlebar appears again, but this does not always happen.

Here we see the correct titlebar with the buttons on the right by default.
[image: pic1]

The moment I change the buttons to the left, the title bar becomes black and the side navigation block disappears.
[image: pic2]

If I resize the window (so the navigation block can be seen again), the titlebar returns, but this not always happens.
[image: pic3]

Even when the titlebar returns by readjusting the window size, I feel like the buttons position is not completely correct... See for example the `Settings` window below, which also has a side navigation block and gives me no problem whatsoever. The `close`, `minimize` and `maximize` buttons are not all the way to the left, but stop at the side navigation block (or maybe it is not correct in `Settings`...).
[image: pic4]

Any clue why this happens and how to solve it? Or am I stuck with titlebar buttons on the right only? Thanks!

Comment: yes, you are rite, I just tried to reproduce the issue and yes..

Comment: this never happened to me with previous releases on the same machine...

Comment: Can confirm. But this is not a general issue. I saw it only for gnome tweaks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid I don't know about Tweaks.

But to move the title bar buttons to the left, the easiest way  is to just copy/paste this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

It takes effect immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just exploring gnome-tweaks (tool) (latest on Ubuntu 20.04 latest) and clicked the button to move the titlebar buttons to the left and then everything broke with regard to the tweak tool and I could not move them back. Your solution helped me quickly recover (just permute the order).